# How to create arrays when setting nested values with paths containing numeric segments

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with figuring out how to modify this setValue() function, so that when it encounters a numeric path segment, an array is created if it doesn't exist. I've tried assigning [] instead of {} when the path segment is numeric but it's not working as expected.

```
var obj = {};

setValue(obj, "Application.0.Employment.0.Id", 1); 

//Not working because objects are not created as arrays   
obj.Application[0].Employment.push({ Id: 2 });


function setValue(object, path, value) {

   var a = path.split('.');
   var o = object;
   for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
          var n = a[i];
          if (n in o) {
              o = o[n];
           } else {
              //o[n] = isNaN(n) ? {} : [];
                o[n] = {};
                o = o[n];
           }
   }
   o[a[a.length - 1]] = value;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look ahead one index. The attempt you had in comments should be altered to:

```
o[n] = isNaN(a[i+1]) ? {} : [];
```

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var a = path.split('.');
    var o = object;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        var n = a[i];
        if (n in o) {
            o = o[n];
        } else {
            o[n] = isNaN(a[i+1]) ? {} : [];
            o = o[n];
        }
    }
    o[a[a.length - 1]] = value;
}

var obj = {};
setValue(obj, "Application.0.Employment.0.Id", 1); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

obj.Application[0].Employment.push({ Id: 2 });
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```